# How to redirect autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)  and I want to open autocomplete list when I focus  myinput but when I clicked any choice than my choice must redirect any link what I want.how can I do that?

```css
.box{
  width:960px;
}
.awesomplete > ul {
 border-radius: .3em;
 margin: .2em 0 0;
 background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, hsla(0,0%,100%,.8));
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 box-shadow: .05em .2em .6em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 text-shadow: none;
}

@supports (transform: scale(0)) {
 .awesomplete > ul {
  transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.4,.2,.5,1.4);
  transform-origin: 1.43em -.43em;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul[hidden],
 .awesomplete > ul:empty {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  display: block;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
 }
}

 /* Pointer */
 .awesomplete > ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -.43em;
  left: 1em;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  padding: .4em;
  background: white;
  border: inherit;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .awesomplete > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li:hover {
  background: hsl(200, 40%, 80%);
  color: black;
 }
 
 .awesomplete > ul > li[aria-selected="true"] {
  background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%);
  color: white;
 }
 
  .awesomplete mark {
   background: hsl(65, 100%, 50%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li:hover mark {
   background: hsl(68, 100%, 41%);
  }
  
  .awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
   background: hsl(86, 100%, 21%);
   color: inherit;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
<input class="awesomplete" list="mylist"/>
  <datalist id="mylist">
 <option>Ada</option>
 <option>Java</option>
 <option>JavaScript</option>
 <option>Brainfuck</option>
 <option>LOLCODE</option>
 <option>Node.js</option>
 <option>Ruby on Rails</option>
</datalist>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

For example when I type `Javascript` or when I selected `Javascript` than page must redirect `http://www.blabla.com`

Comment: Official plugin url have all events available. Have a look here (http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#events) to use `awesomplete-select` event

Comment: yes plugin can be available for this situation but I'm a new on jquery I'm trying to learn how will I use this event

Comment: there is an example something like `Awesomplete.$('.dropdown-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
 if (comboplete.ul.childNodes.length === 0) {
  comboplete.minChars = 0;
  comboplete.evaluate();
 }
 else if (comboplete.ul.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
  comboplete.open();
 }
 else {
  comboplete.close();
 }
});` if you go towards bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a callback to the **oninput** event into to your **input**

```
<input class="awesomplete" oninput="callBack()" list="mylist"/>
```

And then add an script function:

```
function callBack(){
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#datalist").change(function(){
console.log("working");
});
```

```html
set id like this for the input.

<input class="awesomplete" list="mylist" id="datalist"/>
```